# Given $x^5-x^3+x-2=0$, find $\lfloor x^6\rfloor$.

Tags: polynomials, contest-math, roots, factoring, ceiling-and-floor-functions

> If $\alpha$ is a real root of the equation $x^5-x^3+x-2=0$, find the value of $\lfloor\alpha^6\rfloor$, where $\lfloor x\rfloor$ is the least positive integer not exceeding $x$.

My approach is to bound the value of $\alpha^6=\alpha^4-\alpha^2+2\alpha$.

First I proved the function $f(x)=x^5-x^3+x-2$ is monotone increasing by derivative. Then I argue that $1<\alpha<\frac32$ as $f(1)<0$ and $f(\frac32)>0$.

Then I tried to create an upper and lower bound for $\alpha$, as such
$$\alpha^6=\alpha^4-\alpha^2+2\alpha<\frac94\alpha^2-\alpha^2+2\alpha=\frac54\alpha^2+2\alpha<\frac{45}{16}+3=\frac{93}{16}$$
and
$$\alpha^6=\alpha^4-\alpha^2+2\alpha>\alpha^3-\alpha^2+2\alpha=\alpha^2(\alpha-1)+2\alpha>2$$

Now we know that $\lfloor\alpha\rfloor\in\{2,3,4,5\}$. But I cannot proceed any further.

Any idea, help, hint, or answer is appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: If you already know that $1<\alpha<2$, what are you still looking for?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Find $\lfloor {\alpha}^6 \rfloor$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/814162/find-lfloor-alpha6-rfloor). And [If $a$ is a real root of $x^5 − x^3 + x − 2 = 0$, show that $\lfloor a^6 \rfloor = 3$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1652437)

Comment: I am sorry, it was supposed to be $\alpha^6$. Thank you for noticing that.

Comment: Also see all these https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=%24x%5E5-x%5E3%2Bx-2%3D0%24%2C%20%24%5Clfloor%20a%5E6%5Crfloor%24&p=1

Answer (score 3):

Since $f'(x)=5x^4-3x^2+1$, which is always greater than $0$, $f$ is strictly increasing. Since, furthermore, $\lim_{x\to\pm\infty}f(x)=\pm\infty$, $f$ has one and only one real root. On the other hand, $f(1)=-1<0<24=f(2)$. So, the only real root $\alpha$ belongs to $(1,2)$ and $\lfloor\alpha\rfloor=1$.

Answer (score 1):

$$x^5-x^3+x-2=x^5+x^2-(x^2-x+1)-(x^3+1)=$$
$$=(x^2-x+1)(x^3+x^2-x-2).$$
Now, we see that our equation has an unique real root $1<\alpha<2$ and from here $$[\alpha]=1.$$
Now, about your new problem.

Easy to see that for our root $\alpha$ we have $$1.205<\alpha<1.206,$$
which gives $$3<\alpha^6<4$$ and from here: $$[\alpha^6]=3.$$

Comment: Easy to see, really? I feel like [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/814169) is much more practical.

Comment: @Misha Lavrov  I agree. It's nice and easier. Thank you!

Comment: @Misha Lavrov To show $1.205^3+1.205^2-1.205-2<0$ and $1.206^3+1.206^2-1.206-2>0$ it's really easy.